# Entity Framework ExecuteSqlCommand return Object List

Tags: entity-framework, dbcontext

I'm frustated with EF Code First, because of unsupported View Mapping instead of Table.
So i'm switching out with retrieve View Data Class from ExecuteSqlCommand.
But I can't figure out how to do this?
Any help maybe?

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Ignore<m_box>();
    }
protected override void Seed(eBagasiContext context)
    {
        context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(m_boxView.GetInitView(),new object[]{});
     }
public static class m_boxView
{
    public static string GetInitView()
    {
        return "CREATE VIEW m_box " +
            "AS " +
            "SELECT AgencyRef.Code AS ModuleCode, " +                
            "Price.Scale, "+
            "Price.Amount "+
            "FROM Price " +
            "LEFT JOIN AgencyRef " +
            "ON (Price.Code = AgencyRef.Code) " +
            "WHERE LEFT(Price.Code,1)='C'";
    }
}
```

Comment: What error do you get? or what's the result of running this?

Comment: it was model not exists or something because of the ignore command during modelcreate to avoid table creation for a views

Answer (score 0):

If you want to map a view to entity you must follow few steps:

- First map it as a table (so don't ignore `m_box`) and let EF create `m_box` table.
- In your `Seed` method you have to delete that created table and create view with the same name.